# R sort on linux with square bracket in text seems to ignore

Tags: r, regex, linux, sorting

I encountered a strange issue and hoping some one can help me. The job is simple and it seems to work ok on a windows machine but behaves differently. Following is the behavior I see in R version 3.0.2 on a linux machine

```
names <- c('lender1', '[cash]', 'acc1')
names
# [1] "lender1" "[cash]"  "acc1"
sort(names)
# [1] "acc1"    "[cash]"  "lender1"
```

On a windows machine

```
names <- c('lender1', '[cash]', 'acc1')
names
# [1] "lender1" "[cash]"  "acc1"   
sort(names)
# [1] "[cash]"  "acc1"    "lender1"
```

It appears that on Unix machine it is ignoring **[** and sorting the text. How can I force it to use **[** and sort it the way it does on windows platform. These are the column names of a data frame and would need to have **[cash]** coming in the first column. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 6):

This has to do with the 'locale' in which your computer thinks it should perform collation. So I have

```
names <- c('lender1', '[cash]', 'acc1')
Sys.getlocale(category="LC_COLLATE")
## [1] "en_US.UTF-8"
sort(names)
## [1] "acc1"    "[cash]"  "lender1"
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_COLLATE", locale="C")
## [1] "C"
sort(names)
## [1] "[cash]"  "acc1"    "lender1"
```

But the specific locale (and ability to set it interactively) is system-specific. `?Sys.setlocale` has additional information, including a pointer to the `RShowDoc("R-admin")`, the R Installation and Administration manual (section 7).

For the example @bhamu includes in the comment below, I have

```
> Sys.setlocale(category="LC_COLLATE", locale="en_US.UTF-8")
[1] "en_US.UTF_8"
> sort(sectors)
[1] "[Cash]"                 "Consumer Discretionary" "Consumer Staples"      
[4] "[Unassigned]"
```

where in en_US-UTF.8 the '[' character is treated as silent -- ignored during sorting, so Cash sorts before and Unassigned sorts after Consumer. While for

```
> Sys.setlocale(category="LC_COLLATE", locale="C")
[1] "C"
> sort(sectors)
[1] "Consumer Discretionary" "Consumer Staples"       "[Cash]"                
[4] "[Unassigned]"
```

things follow a traditional [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and '[' sorts after upper-case and before lower-case alphabetical characters. Rules for different locales are complex and interesting from a linguistic perspective (I doubt that one can rely on `0` sorting before A-Z in all locales, as implied by @bhamu's work-around suggested below); for many computational tasks one really wants locale="C".

I'm not sure that the following is entirely cross-platform compatible (earlier versions of `?Sys.setlocale()` were less optimistic about whether this worked on Windows, for instance), but an approach to ensure a standard sort order might be

```
mysort <- function(x) {
    olocale <- Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")
    on.exit(Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", olocale))
    sort(x)
}
```

Also, in the case of `sectors` it looks like these are actually factors (character strings indicating one of a finite number of levels), in which case using `lvls` for the in-order representation

```
sectors <- factor(sectors, levels=lvls)
sort(sectors)
```

returns sectors in the desired order.

Comment: Strangely, when I used this on one, I got different results. For this one sectors<- c('[Cash]','[Unassigned]','Consumer Discretionary','Consumer Staples')
> sort(sectors)
[1] "Consumer Discretionary" "Consumer Staples"       "[Cash]"                
[4] "[Unassigned]"

Comment: @bhamu -- tried to clarify in my answer that locales treat symbols differently, e.g., en_US.UTF-8 treats '[' as silent for collation purposes. Neat, eh?

Comment: Wish it is not silent in this case. I replaced the [ with 0[ and sorted them and removed the 0. Wish there is an easier way to get consistent behavior across platforms. Now that I know this, I will be more careful when I am developing cross platform code.